# htaccess help: name1/value1/name2/value2 format

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am designing an admin panel, where I want a structure like this:

```
siteadmin.com/action/edit/id/1/
```

which should return query strings:

```
action => edit
id=>1
```

OR

```
siteadmin.com/action/add/
```

which shd return:

```
action =>add
```

In short, I want something like name1/value1/name2/value2 structure. Here is what I have written:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ index.php?$1=$2 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

But it is taking index_php as well. Any help guys?

Thanks,

Comment: It is not possible with just mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the RewriteRules is important. Also if they are explicit mappings, you often want the `[last]` flag so only one rule matches:

```
RewriteRule  ^from$  to  [last]
```

You should also avoid catch-all patterns, rather define your actions to make it unambigious:

```
RewriteRule ^(action|noaction|delete|explode)/(\d+)$ index?$1=$2 [L]
```

Some more tips on serverfault: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Add `[L]` at the end of the line of your rewrite rule.